# Triggering jquery post on change event

Tags: jquery

I have a select box that I am using to select what data to view in a dashboard.

This is the HTML :

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="item-input">
        <select id="balances">
            <option value="tb">Trading Balance</option>
            <option value="mt">Managed Trading</option>
            <option value="mm">Managed Mining</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="traders">Traders - <b class="gg">3000</b></span>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery :

```
var email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';
$('#balances').on('change', function() {
  var tbalances = this.value;

  if(tbalances === 'tb'){
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';
  }
  if(tbalances === 'mt'){
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_trading_balance';
  }
  if(tbalances === 'mm'){
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_mining_balance';
  }
});
//Get Trading Balance
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: email,
        crossOrigin: true,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
        $('.jbalance').html(data);
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        if(typeof data === 'object'){
        var data = 'No Internet Connection Detected';
        }    
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}, 5 * 1000);
```

On select, the url variable still remains :

`var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';`

I am trying to have the selected option's url be used in the jQuery ajax post request but that is not happening.

How can I have the selected url be used in jquery ajax post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're re-creating another local variable called url using `var url` each time, so the outer variable url won't ever change, and use if else-if instead of multiple if, here's a solution :

```
if(tbalances === 'tb'){
  // no var, just change the already created variable url
  url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';
}
else if(tbalances === 'mt'){
  // no var, just change the already created variable url
  url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_trading_balance';
}
else if(tbalances === 'mm'){
  // no var, just change the already created variable url
  url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_mining_balance';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';
$('#balances').on('change', function() {
 var tbalances = $('#balances').val(); //**change

 if(tbalances.indexOf("tb") >= 0){  //**change
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/trading_balance';
  alert(url);
 }
 if(tbalances.indexOf("mt") >= 0){ //**change
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_trading_balance';
  alert(url);
 }
 if(tbalances.indexOf("mm") >= 0){ //**change
  var url = 'http://example.world/mobile/index.php/welcome/managed_mining_balance';
  alert(url);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="item-input">
        <select id="balances">
         <option value="">-- Choose an Option --</option>
            <option value="tb">Trading Balance</option>
            <option value="mt">Managed Trading</option>
            <option value="mm">Managed Mining</option>
        </select>
    </div><span class="traders">Traders - <b class="gg">3000</b></span>
</div>
```